# is it possible to write A** = B** when B inherits from A?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I have a class Video that inherits from the class Multimedia.
I know that this works:

```
Multimedia* multi;
Video* vid;
multi = vid;
```

But, I don't understand why the following code doesn't:

```
    Multimedia** m;
    Video** v;
    m = v;

error: invalid conversion from ‘Video**’ to ‘Multimedia**’ [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Because whilst a `Video` [is a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) type of `Multimedia`, a pointer-to-`Video` is not a type of pointer-to-`Multimedia`.

Comment: Because an item of type `Video*` is not also of type `Multimedia*`.

Comment: You need to cast i.e. `m = (Multimedia**) v;`

Comment: @user0042 The error arises from the use of double pointers.

Comment: @JakeFreeman that would cause undefined behaviour if `m` is later dereferenced

Comment: @JakeFreeman Yeah that's what I did I used cast. But, I was wondering if there was another way to do it. I haven't seen the duplicates.

Comment: @J.M.Aziz -- Do not cast.  The compiler is letting you know that the types are not the same.  By applying a C-style case, you're telling the compiler that you know better, and to shut-up.  The compiler knows better.